# Android webview download file response from django

Tags: android

I've an Android app with webview and Backend is Django,
There's a view sending FileResponse, I tried everything possible to get the response, but was unable to do the same

```
        superWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "downloaded-pdf");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Using this downloadListener,I get HTML file downloaded instead of the response(Which is pdf)
Is there any way I can intercept the response?

Comment: What is the URL you are getting in onDownloadStart?

Comment: I get the URL of the view which responds with the FileResponse

Comment: https://meetdev26.github.io/android-addict/#/download-file